# Need horizontal scrolling after vertical page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have code structure like this

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="horizontal-gallery">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

and i need to start horizontal scrolling my gallery and when it ends need to scroll down page as usual. how i can change vertical scroll to horizontal when reach gallery and after turn back to vertical scrolling? so i dont have any ideas

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some interesting juggling here.

1. When the page loads, set overflow-x to none (or the width of the gallery to fit the page)
2. When the gallery comes into view (which you'll have to monitor for via JS or similar) you'll have to revert #1 above (overflow-x: auto or set the width)

Basically, you want the page to dynamically enable/disable horizontal scrolling. The only way to do that is to monitor for when that needs to apply and apply it yourself.